# touchesBegan for UITable's Cell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, sdk, touches

How can I use touchesbegan in a table's cell without having to subclass a whole cell. Something like addTarget..... which is available for a UIButton?

(in vb.net this would be like AddHandler I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must subclass `UITableViewCell` in order to have access to individual touches on a tableview cell.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it, you will have to subclass UITableView cell just like the post before me said, then you can add some view in the cells content view there which can delegate the touches to the tableviewcontroller or wherever they need to go...

Answer (score 0):

@Jaco Relkin, you can implement the messages on the UITableViewDelegateProtocol, for example: the message tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: documented here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: